# Wordpress: Get the contents of another page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating something for a filter for a SEO plugin and I want to find a way to be able to get the contents of another specific post from another page (note this code will most likely run in the admin panel).

The way I wished to do it was like so:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile(get_permalink($post->ID));
// Some more code before saving the HTML
```

and it works fine except that it doesn't work on my production shared server (probably due to a security reason).

I would also prefer a more efficient way of doing it without breaking other aspects of the page.

Note I also tried:

```
  ob_start();
  include get_template_directory() . '/single-' . $post->post_type . '.php';
  $html = ob_get_clean();
```

However this broke some of the stuff on the admin panel.

Is there a better way getting the "CONTENTS" of another page of the site using and storing it as a string in a variable in Wordpress, without breaking anything.

**Update**
To make my question clearer please note I want to get the FULL HTML (not just an aspect of it).

Also I am unable to send http requests to the same server (due to a restriction on the shared server). Aditional Http requests would be nice to avoid anyways for performance reasons. After all WordPress is already booted and running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION 1: file_get_contents**

Use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) as shown below.

```
$content = file_get_contents(get_permalink($post->ID));
```

In order to use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), PHP configuration option [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) in `php.ini` should be enabled. If you use shared hosting, `allow_url_fopen` may be disabled and/or your hosting provider may not allow you to change it.

**SOLUTION 2: cURL**

Alternatively,  you can use [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). In order to use it, PHP must have built-in cURL support or have cURL extension installed.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $get_permalink($post->ID));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$content = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Yes I think that'll work as well (similar to my Dom document one), but won't work on my shared server as it is an external request to the same domain due to a security restriction (or else I would have just used the DOM document way).

Comment: Valid solutions, but like I said I can't send http requests to the same host due to a restriction of the shared server. Aditional Http requests would be nice to avoid anyways for performance reasons. After all WordPress is already booted and running.

Comment: @YahyaUddin, surprisingly there seemed to be no simple pure Wordpress solution to this, maybe would you consider front-end solution instead. For example, JavaScript function that gets post content using `$.get` and sends HTML content to server-side PHP script for analysis.

Comment: Marked this as correct as closest to answer as I'm probably gonna get

Answer (score 0):

If you are not trying to get the full html of a page but just the content of another post, then this will work:

```
<?php
$post_id = 3; //use the id you need here
$post = get_post( $post_id ); //post content is in $post->post_content
```

Comment: Sorry trying to get the full html.

Comment: How about using wp_remote_get() to request the page/post you want?
It would be a normal request processed by the server then wordpress, and should result in the creation of the html resource you want.